# Kubernetes how to make Deployment to update image auto CI/CD

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, google-kubernetes-engine, flux

I am using gcp and kubernetes.

I have gcp repository and container registry.

I have a trigger for build container after pushing into the master branch.

I don't know how to set some auto-trigger to deploy new version of the container (docker file).

How can I automate the build process?

Answer (score 2):

You need some extra pieces to do it, for example if you use Helm to package your deployment you can use Flux to trigger the automated deployment.

https://helm.sh/

https://fluxcd.github.io/flux/

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions here.

1. You can expand the `build` step. Cloud Build can also push changes to your GKE cluster. You can read more about this [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/gitops-cloud-build)
2. What you currently have is a solid CI pipeline, for the CD, you can use [Spinnaker for GCP](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/devops-sre/introducing-spinnaker-for-google-cloud-platform-continuous-delivery-made-easy), which was released recently. This integrates well with GCE, GKE and GAE and allows you to automate the CD portion.